# Undefined index and using isset

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code in my wordpress theme that is giving me 2 notices

I'm not 100% sure how to fix it. I have tried using `isset()` but it's not working for me and keep getting different errors.

```
$post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'];
$template_file = get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_page_template',TRUE);
$array = array('template-homepage1.php', 'template-homepage2.php');
```

Comment: Simply use `$_REQUEST`

Comment: @Baba: How should that work in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try it.

```
 if(isset($_GET['post']))
   {  
   $post_id = $_GET['post'];
    }
 if(isset($_POST['post_ID']))  
    {
   $post_id =  $_POST['post_ID'] ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to intialize variable first or check with empty() or isset() for php ignore notices

```
$post_id = '';$template_file='';
$post_id = (!empty($_GET['post']) ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID']) ;

$template_file = get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_page_template',TRUE);
$array = array('template-homepage1.php', 'template-homepage2.php');
```

Or try to off php notices from php.ini

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `isset()` to check if `$_GET` variable and `if else` condition to assign values wherever it needs to

```
if(isset($_GET['post']) 
{
    $post_id = $_GET['post'];
} else {
    if(isset($_POST['post_ID']) 
    { 
         $post_id = $_POST['post_ID'];
    } else {
         $post_id = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$post_id = isset($_GET['post']) ? $_GET['post'] : isset($_POST['post_ID']) ? $_POST['post_ID'] : 0 ;
```

but in this way using if may be more readable

```
$post_id = 0;

if(isset($_GET['post'])) $post_id = $_GET['post'];
else if(isset($_POST['post_ID']) $post_id = $_POST['post_ID'];
```

Comment: Nested ternary operators. Beautiful.